# JQuery Flexigrid change label edit

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

How to change label edit to another text? Normally the label is Add, Edit, Delete. I will change edit to view or display as my goal when user click on this link, it will go to edit form but all field are readonly (user unable to edit data) so it looks strange when the title is edit

Comment: i have done this by myself, thank's a lot

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help u

```
    function conditionalDialog(mode){
    var theButtons = {};
    var theautoOpen = true;
    var title = "";

    if (mode=='first'){
        theautoOpen = false;    }
    if (mode=='Add'){
        title = "Add Product Record";
        theButtons["Save"] = function() { simpan('add'); Tambah(); };
        theButtons["Close"] = function() { $(this).dialog("close"); };
    }else{
        title = "Edit Product Record";
        theButtons["Save"] = function() { simpan('edit'); $(this).dialog("close"); };
        theButtons["Cancel"] = function() { $(this).dialog("close"); };
    }
    $('#form').dialog("option","title",title);
    $('#form')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: theautoOpen,
        width: 600, 
        buttons: theButtons,
        show:"slide"
    }); 
}
```

u can see at line $('#form').dialog("option","title",title); 
it will change label